# Java + Powermockito: How to Replace or Mock Thread.sleep method

Tags: java, powermockito

Using PowerMockito, I have been trying to replace or mock the Thread.sleep method.
Wherein, the replacing or mocking method will return and Exception.
I have tried the following examples but no luck:

```
PowerMockito.replace(PowerMockito.method(Thread.class, "sleep", long.class))
        .with((object, method, arguments) -> {
            throw new Exception(someRandomExceptionMessage);
        });

 PowerMockito.when(Thread.class, "sleep", anyLong()).thenThrow(new Exception(someRandomExceptionMessage));
 PowerMockito.when(Thread.class, "sleep", 1000L).thenThrow(new Exception("An Exception"));
```

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It is important to note the @PrepareForTest needs to refer the method calling Thread.sleep(), not Thread itself.

```
class ClassCallingSleep {
    public static void methodCallingSleep() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("TEST 1");
        Thread.sleep(100L);
        System.out.println("TEST 2");
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ClassCallingSleep.class})
public class SleepTest {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Thread.class);
        PowerMockito.doThrow(new InterruptedException("HAHA!")).when(Thread.class);
        Thread.sleep(Mockito.anyLong());

        ClassCallingSleep.methodCallingSleep();
    }
}
```

Output is as follows (that is, TEST 2 above is not reached).

TEST 1

java.lang.InterruptedException: HAHA!

Comment: yes I did all of that.

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: if you copy the above snippet exactly, what happens? It works for me (for reference, powermock 1.6.1, mockito 1.10.8, junit 4.12)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have an `underTest` class calling a function that is using `Thread.sleep`?

You can rather write your test in this way :

- if you have a `delay` variable that returns the execution duration, you can mock the returned value instead of directly mocking `Thread.sleep` and then test your `exception` with `@Test(expected = Exception.class)` or `Exception thrownException = assertThrows()` depending on wether you are using `JUnit 4` or `JUnit 5`
- if you are using `JUnit 5`, you can simply use `assertTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10),() -> { underTest.yourMethodCallingThreadSleep())`
- if using `Mockito`, the last version can allows you to mock `static` methods

Take as a suggestion and a simple way to write your test.